# Can I resynchronise my Subaru (Cobra) key fob

Tags: subaru, locks, fob, forester

I accidentally placed a heavy object on my key fob at home. It must have been there for more than five minutes before I noticed the little light flashing on the fob.

Since then I have not been able to lock or unlock the car using the fob or set or reset the alarm or immobiliser, although the light still flashes on the fob when I press it. I have replaced the battery, but still no joy.

My assumption is that it has lost synch with the car, and my plan is to get it sorted when I take the car in for next service as I have a workaround (use the key and a manual alarm reset) - this is what the manual recommends.

But is there a way to resynch the key myself?

**Update:** This is a specialist import 2006 Forester STi with a CAT 5 immobiliser. And I have discovered it is a Cobra fob.

Comment: Is it possible the battery is simply low? It may have been continuously transmitting when the button was held down. Does the manual say anything useful? What model and year?

Comment: I would think a new battery might be in order as well. Remember that the fob is tied to the car, not the other way around. This means the fob has a transponder which is loaded into the car's body control module memory. The fob is just fat-dumb-and-happy (is a dumb device). The car will either recognize the fob or not. As long as the fob is able to transmit, the car should recognize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the way to resynch a Cobra key fob is to hold both buttons down for about 6-8 seconds, or until the flashing lights stop flashing. You then release the buttons, and press each of them once.

Update: It turns out there is even a Cobra Car Tech YouTube channel, and they have a [video showing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNJJ9u9aDqg) what I have described above.